# Command prompt inside a java program

Tags: java, command-line, prompt

So I want to make a java application which, while running, can run custom commands (not windows commands, commands for my application) from the command line, I can already do it, but I'd like to have a prompt such as `>` where you'd type commands, how can I output `>` and then remove it when it's time to print something else to that line?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I'm probably not describing this clearly, I mean, so that at the bottom of all the output there's a `>` and you'd type commands on the right side of it, so it looks like a prompt.

Comment: If that `>` needs to be removed from the console after executing the command, maybe using the backspace character (ASCII code 8) could work? Seems hacky, but who knows.

Comment: So far, @G_H has the best suggestion. Feel free to post it as a answer G_H,

Comment: Yes, it works nearly flawlessly, at least for my purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Java 6, you can use the [`Console`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class for that. Specifically, the `readLine` method. From the API:

> public String readLine(String fmt, Object... args)
>
> ```
>    Provides a formatted prompt, then reads a single line of text from the console.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with PaoloVictor's recommendation of using `Console`, but if you're more curious about architecture I might suggest a REPL (Read, Evaluate, Print Loop). Where you would do something like this.

```
init();
while(1){

   System.out.print("myProgram>");
   String cmd = Console.readLine(String fmt, Object... args);
   evaluate(cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good library, [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/), does exactly what I want.